# Eclipse : Configuring Jetty 8 in Eclipse .

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I am trying to configure Jetty 8 in my Eclipse IDE .
I have got Version 8 as Jetty Server .
I am trying to configure Jetty8 from Eclipse .

I have download the Jetty Adapter through Eclipse (Additional  Server adapters)

When i tried to configure Jetty 8 from Eclipse IDE Servers Section , The problem is taht , it is not showing Jetty 8 in the list , its only showing the Jetty 6 .

Please see the screen shot of the above .

[image: Screenshot]

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: printscreen is too small

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to select Jetty 8 in Eclipse if you use `RunJettyRun` plugin:

`Run Configurations -> Jetty Webapp -> YourProject -> Select a Jetty Version`

Comment: WTP is *NOT* needed.  RunJettyRun is a far better alternative to WTP.

Comment: @PreethiJain, agree with Joakim, just use RunJettyRun